# What's the first pin of OPA2365?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, operational-amplifier

Usually I recognize the first pin of an IC by observing the small circle and then comparing it with the layout in the datasheet, but in the OPA2365 there is no circle.

In the image, is the red arrow pointing to pin 1?

[image]

Comment: std for most if not all SOIC’s is bottom left corner =1 reading text correctly, then top view CCW incr #

Answer (score 1):

Indeed that probably is pin 1.

But to be 100% sure, consult the datasheet:

[image]

Note how the pin 1 side has a different edge, noted by the circles.

Comment: I've seen my IC, the pin shown in the picture with the red arrow is on the edge at 45 degrees. So to recognize the first pin, the edge at 45 degrees must be on the left side?

Answer (score 1):

On that part, the white bar marks the pin 1 end. On many parts, there is a notch on the pin 1 end.

Also, if you hold the part so the text is readable, pin 1 will usually be the bottom left pin.

Many packages have a bevel along the pin one edge (look at the end o the package to see this).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell, because these op-amps have had multiple production runs with different styles silk screened on them. They were originally Brown Burr parts before TI purchased them, and factory changes from one production facility to another. They are old designs, and highly counterfeited, to were its hard to tell if legit unless you get them straight from TI. There has been history of even legit distributors ending up with fakes.

[image]

A legit TI part should have the pin 1 side of it's package beveled. Significantly enough to the other side, which is almost squared off/90 degrees parallel to the face. **In the picture above, you can see it's almost 45 degrees from the face.

Your picture is also a bit unclear, damaged or a really bad counterfeit because there is a dimple next to the first line, on the left of the picture. That would typically indicate that that's pin 1, but the text is upside down, which is very very rare for a DIP or SOIC package.